# From a string using java script or jquery how to fetch list of values mentioned in between two delimiters?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sample Input :- `(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)`

Expected output :- `1A,2,100Baxc02,1000D33,10001HGA`

Note :- Length of input is not fixed it varies.

My code so far:

```js
var AlertExpressionWithUid = "(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)";
theArray = AlertExpressionWithUid.split(';');
output="";
for (i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
  theelm = theArray[i];
  output = output + theelm;
}
alert(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to match substrings between `;`s which don't contain `&&` - why not use a regular expression? Using lookbehind:

```js
const AlertExpressionWithUid = "(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)";
const matches = AlertExpressionWithUid.match(/(?<=;)[^;&]+(?=;)/g);
console.log(matches);
```

Or, since lookbehind is supported only in newer browsers, without lookbehind, you'll have to use a loop instead:

```js
const AlertExpressionWithUid = "(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)";
const re = /;([^;&]+);/g;
let match;
const matches = [];
while ((match = re.exec(AlertExpressionWithUid)) !== null) {
  matches.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need the values with odd index of splited array so use a condition in your `for` loop as `i%2 !== 0`. Since, you need

```js
var AlertExpressionWithUid ="(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)";
var output=[];
var theArray = AlertExpressionWithUid.split(';');
for (i=0;i<theArray.length;i++)
{
  if(i%2 !== 0){
    output.push(theArray[i]);
  }
}
output = output.join(',');
console.log(output) ;
```

You can also refactor your code to use `Array.filter()` like this:

```js
var AlertExpressionWithUid ="(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)";
var theArray = AlertExpressionWithUid.split(';');
var output = theArray.filter((item, index) => index%2 !==0 ).join(',');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
var AlertExpressionWithUid = "(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)";
theArray = AlertExpressionWithUid.split(';');
var output='';
for (i = 1; i < theArray.length; i+=2) {
  theelm = theArray[i];
  output = output +','+ theelm;
}
console.log(output.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot have `<` as a value, try this filter

```js
var AlertExpressionWithUid = "(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)",
res = AlertExpressionWithUid.split(";")
       .filter(function(item) { return item.indexOf("<") ==-1 });
res.shift(); // drop the leading "("
console.log(res.join(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var AlertExpressionWithUid = "(;1A;<1&&;2;<2&&;100Baxc02;<3&&;1000D33;<4&&;10001HGA;<5)";
    AlertExpressionWithUid = AlertExpressionWithUid.substring(1, AlertExpressionWithUid.length-1);//remove "(" and ")"
    theArray = AlertExpressionWithUid.split(';');
    output="";
    for (i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
      if (i%2!=0)
        output = output + (output != '' ? ',' : '') + theArray[i];
    }
alert(output);
```